# React form prepend the base url

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

How I can stop prepending the default URL when using Axios post or fetch

```js
const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
event.preventDefault();
axios.post(`/auth/login`, formData)
```

In browser devtools the error:

```js
POST http://localhost:3000/localhost:4000/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
```

In app.tsx, i've made axios base url to the backend API

```js
axios.defaults.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4000';
```

Form is setup like this:

```js
<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
... material ui elements
</form>
```

There is no place everywhere in the codebase where I've put `http://localhost:3000`

BR,